# Running python bot in django background

Tags: python, django

I've got a django project with simple form to take users details in. I want to use python bot running in the background and constantly checking django database for any changes. Is it Celery the right tool for this job? Any other solution? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Celery is really what you want here - Celery is primarily for moving tasks that don't need to be dealt with in the same process to a separate worker, such as sending registration emails.

For this situation I'd be inclined to use [Django's signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/) to trigger the required functionality whenever the appropriate changes are made to the database. For instance, if it needed to be triggered when a particular type of object was created, such as a new user, then you might use the `post_save` signal of the user model.

The bot would be in a separate process, but it's not too hard to communicate between processes using Redis. Just have the signal publish a message to Redis, and have the bot listen for that message and carry out the required action on that event.

Comment: Thank you so much, Matthew. That's the answer I was looking for. Just trying to build my first django project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the details of your needs but, there are a few ways to achieve such things:

The Constantly checking approach:

- [A crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) which launch your python script every minute.
- Like you said, you could use [Celery beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.beat.html), to achieve what a crontab would do, in your python environment

"On change" approach:

- Probably the best, if you have control of the Django project, you could have your script run on the form validation/save! For this, You can add a celery task, run the python script, use Django signals...